# Sacar el ultimo registro de cada group by en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, orderby

Tengo que mostrar en un filtro, los ultimos registros, en este caso de cada maquina y cada útil.
Y no me funciona correctamente porque depende en el filtro del util que le ponga, es decir si cambio y busco por otro util a lo mejor me salen fechas de 2018 cuando el ultimo es de 2021.

Mi query es esta:

```
    SELECT  * FROM  AM_MONTAJE T1 
    WHERE util like '%3824%' AND prueba=0 AND obsoleto=0 AND antiguo=0 and alertCalibrada=0 AND
                (T1.fecha in (SELECT MAX(fecha)
                FROM AM_MONTAJE
                WHERE util like '%3824%' group by util,maquina )  
                ) group by util,maquina order by fecha desc;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La cosa esta en que en la maquina MTWEL370 no sale el ultimo registro si no uno de 2018
Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, gracias de antemano

Comment: Deberías añadir los datos de la BBDD o por lo menos un ejemplo de los datos y los campos de la misma.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo , es la primera vez que genero una pregunta aqui

Comment: En estos casos es recomendable revisar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Según el ejemplo aportado, el ultimo registro de la maquina `MTWEL370 ` es del 2018, por lo tanto no veo el problema en tu consulta.

Comment: El último registro de la maquina MTWEL370  que aparece en mi consulta si que es uno de 2018, pero comento anteriormente mi problema es que ese no es el ultimo registro ya que existe uno de 2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción puede ser:

```sql
SELECT
  MAX(`AM_MONTAJE`.`id`) `id`,
  `AM_MONTAJE`.`util`,
  `AM_MONTAJE`.`maquina`,
  `der`.`max_fecha` `fecha`
FROM
  `AM_MONTAJE`
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      `maquina`,
      MAX(`fecha`) `max_fecha`
    FROM
      `AM_MONTAJE`
    WHERE
      `util` LIKE '%3824%'
    GROUP BY
      `maquina`  
  ) `der` ON
  `AM_MONTAJE`.`maquina` = `der`.`maquina` AND
  `AM_MONTAJE`.`fecha` = `der`.`max_fecha`
GROUP BY
  `AM_MONTAJE`.`util`,
  `AM_MONTAJE`.`maquina`,
  `der`.`max_fecha`;
```

Ver ejemplo [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c56f746d61941283d487cb3dc5915974).

Al no disponer de la estructura real de la tabla `AM_MONTAJE`, asumí una estructura ajustada a la consulta mostrada, pero podrá ajustarla según necesite.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido de gran ayuda tu query, estoy muy agradecido.

Comment: @PandaKontrol, si la respuesta te resolvió el problema marcala como aceptada y dale un voto

Comment: @Japv, si ya la marqué como aceptada y le voté positivo, pero como mi cuenta es nueva todavía no aparecen mis votos aunque si que cuenten.