# Consulta ultimo registro de una tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

Estoy intentando sacar el último registro de cada útil ( consultando la columna fecha ) que puede tener varias maquinas en las que aparezca el útil.

La tabla es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como resultado me deberia sacar solo 2 registros, que serian:

el id 4381 y el id 4342.

He intentando agrupar por maquina o por util, pero me he dado cuenta de que 1 útil puede estar en varias máquinas y en una máquina puede tener varios utiles.

Y he probado con esta query pero me saca los ultimos registros de hoy:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE fecha = (SELECT MAX(fecha) from tabla)
```

Comment: Por favor, muestra los resultados esperados, y los resultados que estás obteniendo ahora, como lo hiciste con la tabla. Y si estas consultando por fecha MAX, obtendrás solo esa max fecha.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Sacar el ultimo registro de cada group by en mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/466320/sacar-el-ultimo-registro-de-cada-group-by-en-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select max(id), util, maquina, max(fecha) 
from tabla 
group by util, maquina
```

Utilizas la **cláusula group by** y agrupas por los **campos util** y **maquina** y en el **select** utilizas la **función de agregación max** al **campo fecha** para obtener la fecha más reciente por cada grupo, como también quieres recuperar el **campo id** le aplicas también una **función de agregación** ya que en **SQL** debe cumplirse la regla de que el **campo que no aparece en el **group by** debe aparecer en el **select** con una función de agregación**, es decir si al **campo id** no le pones una función de agregación como este no aparece en el **group by** pues la consulta dará error.

Comment: Gracias por aclararme la consulta, asi consigo entender el porque la manera de hacerlo así. Me ha servido tu respuesta!